# Как сделать, чтобы бот отвечал определённым людям?

Tags: python, telegram, telebot, aiogram, бот

Допустим, у меня есть бот на python telebot, который должен отвечать только людям из списка users, в котором несколько user id. C одним обработчиком(message_handler) и функцией(send_message_user) можно сделать это через условие:

---

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot('api')
users = [1234567, 7654321]

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_message_user(message):
    if message.from_user.id in users:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Hello')
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'error')
```

---

Но если таких функций и обработчиков много? Это неудобно добавлять проверку в каждую функцию, + будет повторяться код не один раз. Есть ли другие решения? Основного бота пишу на aiogram, если в этой библиотеке предусмотрен инструмент для решения данной ситуации я был бы рад его найти. (:

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать примерно так

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'],
                     func=lambda message: message.from_user.id in users
                    )
def send_message_user(message: types.Message) -> None:
    if message.text == 'start':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'hello')
```

Comment: лучше использовать фильтры, а не этот костыль

Comment: можно и фильтры